# Html.BeginForm() type of extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Does anyone know the syntax for creating a custom HtmlHelperextension method which behaves like..

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

<p>Loads of html stuff here </p>

<% } %>
```

I'm thinking of something along the lines of....

Any ideas?

Cheers,

ETFairfax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a class that implements `IDisposable` interface and return that from your `HtmlHelper`.

```
public static class HtmlHelperTableExtensions {
    private class TableRenderer : IDisposable {
        HtmlHelper html;
        public TableRenderer(HtmlHelper html) {
           this.html = html;
        }
        public void Dispose() {
           HtmlHelperTableExtensions.EndTable(html);
        }
    }
    public static IDisposable BeginTable(this HtmlHelper html) {
        // print begin table here...
        return new TableRenderer(html);
    }
    public static void EndTable(this HtmlHelper html) {
        // print end table here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify for those reading this, you need to call HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<yourtag>"); in the places that Mehrdadhas written // print begin table here, and // print end table here.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have a method something like this:

```
public static IDisposable BeginTable(this HtmlHelper html, ...)
{
    // write the start of the table here

    return new EndTableWriter();
}
```

Where the `EndTableWriter` is something like this:

```
private class EndTableWriter : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // write the end of the table here
    }
}
```