# Creating Some thing @using (Html.BeginForm()) Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In Asp.net MVC3 when you write below code , it generates wrapping html itself

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
}
```

It generates codes in below format,

```
<form method="post" action="/Feeds">
   <!-- Fields Here -->
</form>
```

My question in  `@using (Html.BeginForm())` automatically adds `<form>` tag at beginning and end, how can i create something like that of my own.

### I am looking for some thing like below

```
@using (Html.BeginMYCUSTOMDIV())
  {
        I am text inside div
  }
```

**Expected Generated Output**

```
<div class="customDivClass">
I am text inside div
</div>
```

Comment: This should be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676746/custom-html-helpers-create-helper-with-using-statement-support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
public class MyDiv : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter _writer;
    public MyDiv(TextWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _writer.WriteLine("</div>");
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static MyDiv BeginMYCUSTOMDIV(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("customDivClass");
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(div.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new MyDiv(htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer);
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginMYCUSTOMDIV())
{
    <span>Hello</span>
}
```

generates:

```
<div class="customDivClass">
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'BeginMYCUSTOMDIV' and no extension method 'BeginMYCUSTOMDIV' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  getting this error

Comment: @Rusi Nova, did you brought the namespace containing the `MyExtensions` static class into scope in your view? Like `@using Foo.Bar` on the top of your Razor page? Or like adding this namespace to the `<namespaces>` section of the `~/Views/web.config`? It's the way extension method works. Html helpers in ASP.NET MVC are nothing more than extension methods. So they has to be brought into scope for you to use them.

Comment: oh thanx!! got your point, and now its running fine.  I am planning to shift `MyExtensions` class  inside `System.Web.Mvc.Html`  namespace, is this a good idea??

Comment: @Rusi Nova, yeah, why not. That way it will be accessible automatically, because the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace is into scope. Is there anything else you would like to ask about?

Comment: thanx, `"That way it will be accessible automatically"`: that was the reason i decided to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, `Html.BeginForm()` returns an `IDisposable` object. When used in the `using` block, the object's `Dispose`method is called, which is the responsible to write the closing tag to the output.

[how does using HtmlHelper.BeginForm() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121065/how-does-using-htmlhelper-beginform-work)

[Html.BeginForm() type of extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648711/html-beginform-type-of-extension)